# Understanding Functions With Recurrence

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

I'm having a heck of a time understanding what is being asked of me and every time I check my answer, I'm being told it's wrong but not understanding where and why.

```
Suppose f: N 7→ N satisfies the recurrence f(n + 1) = f(n) + 3. For each of the initial conditions below, find the value of f(5).


a) f(0) = 0
b) f(0) = 1
c) f(0) = 2
d) f(0) = 100
```

Now I think my issue is that my understanidng of functions is coming more from an algebra/calculus understanding so I'm thinking that inputs should match outputs. But this is wrong.

Here is the work I tried to understand recurrence.

```
a) F(0) = 0
  
 F(0 + 1) = f(1) + 3 = 4
   F(1+ 1) = f(2) + 3 = 5
   F( 2 + 1) = f(3) + 3 = 6
    F( 3 + 1) = f(4) + 3 = 7  
    F( 4 + 1) = f(5) + 3 = 8
    
    b)  F(0) = 1
    
    F(1 + 1) = F(2) + 3
    F(2 + 3) = F(5) + 3
    F(5 + 3) = F(8) + 3
    F(8 + 3) = F(11) + 3
    F(11+3) = F(14) + 3 
    
    
    
    c)  F(0) = 2
    F(2 + 1)  = F (3) + 3
    F(6 + 1) = F ( 7) + 3
    F( 10 + 1) = F(11) + 3
    F(14 + 1) = F(15) + 3
    F(18 + 1) = F(18) + 3
    
    
    
    d)  F(0) = 100
    F(100 + 1) = f(101) + 3 = 104
    F(104 + 1) = f(104) + 3 = 107
    F(107 + 1) = f(108) + 3 = 111
    F(111 + 1) = f(112) + 3  = 115
    F(115 + 1) = f(115) + 3 = 118
```

My answer is wrong but I'm not understanding or misinterpreting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a notation error when you write, for example, $f(0+1) = f(1) + 3$. The recursion statement $f(n + 1) = f(n) + 3$ means that for any *fixed* value of $n$, the evaluation of $f$ at $n+1$ is equal to the evaluation of $f$ at $n$, plus 3 - that is, you should be replacing $n$ with the same thing on both sides, which looks something like this:

$\begin{array}{lrcl}
n = 0: & f(0 + 1) & = & f(0) + 3 \\
& f(1) & = & 0 + 3 \\
& & = & 3 \\
n = 1: & f(1 + 1) & = & f(1) + 3 \\
& f(2) & = & 3 + 3 \\
& & = & 6 \\
n = m + 1: & f(m + 1 + 1) & = & f(m + 1) + 3 \\
& f(m + 2) & = & (f(m) + 3) + 3 \\
& & = & f(m) + 6\end{array}$

They're still functions - there's still an input and an output, but we're describing the output at one value in terms of the output of another. Compare that to, for example, $f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$, which is a recurrence relation that holds true for $f(x) = \sin x$, among other functions, and which you can check the truth of by looking at various values of $x$ (e.g. $\sin 2\pi = \sin 0$, $\sin (2 \pi + \frac{1}{2}) = \sin \frac{1}{2}$).